# Find the combination of a particular elements with its other column element

Tags: r

My file is like this-

```
   Pcol       Mcol
    P1      M1,M2,M5,M6
    P2      M1,M2,M3,M5
    P3      M4,M5,M7,M6
```

I want to `find the combination of Mcol elements along with Pcol`.

Expected output-

```
Pcol Mcol        
P1  M1,M2        
P2  M1,M2        
P1  M1,M5        
P2  M1,M5        
P1  M1,M6        
P1  M2,M5        
P2  M2,M5        
P1  M2,M6        
P1  M5,M6        
P3  M5,M6        
P2  M1,M3        
P2  M2,M3        
P3  M4,M5        
P3  M4,M7        
P3  M4,M6        
P3  M7,M6
```

I have tried this-

```
x <- read.csv("file.csv" ,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xx <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
              lapply(x$Gcol, function(i){
                n <- sort(unlist(strsplit(i, ",")))
                t(combn(n, 2))
              }))
```

But it only gives output of combination not the Pcol elements.

Comment: No, that was for frequency n here I need 1st column element also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following similar to your approach we can use `Map` instead of `lapply` to get `Pcol` elements

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) data.frame(Pcol=x, Mcol=combn(y, 2, toString)), 
               df$Pcol, strsplit(df$Mcol, ",")))


#   Pcol   Mcol
#1    P1 M1, M2
#2    P1 M1, M5
#3    P1 M1, M6
#4    P1 M2, M5
#5    P1 M2, M6
#6    P1 M5, M6
#7    P2 M1, M2
#8    P2 M1, M3
#9    P2 M1, M5
#10   P2 M2, M3
#11   P2 M2, M5
#12   P2 M3, M5
#13   P3 M4, M5
#14   P3 M4, M7
#15   P3 M4, M6
#16   P3 M5, M7
#17   P3 M5, M6
#18   P3 M7, M6
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Mcol = list(combn(str_split(Mcol, ",")[[1]], 2, toString))) %>%
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to separate the 'Mcol' with `separate_rows`, grouped by 'Pcol', get the `combn` of 'values' and `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   separate_rows(Mcol) %>% 
   group_by(Pcol) %>% 
   summarise(Mcol = list(combn(Mcol, 2, FUN = toString))) %>%
   unnest
# A tibble: 18 x 2
#   Pcol   Mcol
#   <fct> <chr> 
# 1 P1    M1, M2
# 2 P1    M1, M5
# 3 P1    M1, M6
# 4 P1    M2, M5
# 5 P1    M2, M6
# 6 P1    M5, M6
# 7 P2    M1, M2
# 8 P2    M1, M3
# 9 P2    M1, M5
#10 P2    M2, M3
#11 P2    M2, M5
#12 P2    M3, M5
#13 P3    M4, M5
#14 P3    M4, M7
#15 P3    M4, M6
#16 P3    M5, M7
#17 P3    M5, M6
#18 P3    M7, M6
```